# If body doesn't have a class, then change the margin on the header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write an if statement that says, if the body doesn't have a class of "home" then make the margin of header as 0.

I tried this and it is not working:

```
if (!$("body").hasClass("home")){
    $("header").css("margin", "0");            
}
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2U4N3/. Is your code in a document ready call or at the end of the page?

Comment: body[class=''] header { margin:0; } for IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use pure css:

```
body:not(.home) header {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not in IE8 or lower though.

Comment: Question doesn't ask for a CSS solution and isn't tagged with CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that I could just do this with pure CSS. Much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another pure CSS way (works in all browsers):

```
header {margin:0;}
body.home header {margin:10px; /* or whatever you want it to be */}
```

Comment: Question doesn't ask for a CSS solution and isn't tagged with CSS.

Comment: @j08691: It's an equivalent solution based on what's provided in the OP, and utilizes what's already available in the browser. It's not like they need to go download a library to use the solution.

Comment: @j08691 the OP is very new here, and it's possible he/she did not realize that it could be done in CSS.  We would be negligent not to include this as an answer here.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct - I was overthinking it and didn't realize that I could just do it with pure CSS. Thank you :)